# Heroku review apps - How to prevent an environment variable from being copied from parent app

Tags: heroku

[app.json documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#env) doesn't instruct how to **prevent** environment variables from being copied over.

My issue is that we are using a CDN in Staging app (the parent), but not in review apps, and therefore only want to configure our CDN if the required key is provided by the environment variables.

Is there a reason this isn't documented?

Thanks